# how to defined subset of highest n values from a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is the accurate way define a subset of n highest values from a set?
Lets say we have set $A=\text{{4,2,5,8,1}}$.

if $n=2$, i want $B=\text{{5,8}}$, if $n=3$ then $B=\text{{4,5,8}}$ and so on. how to define $B$ mathematically?

something similar to this: 
$B = \{x | x \in A \land \forall y \in A \land y \notin B \Rightarrow y\leq x \} \land |B|=n $

thanks.

Comment: I think you will get into trouble for non-predicativity, i.e., you cannot use B to define B.

Comment: right, then what is the best mathematical way to define that set?

Comment: O.K, let me look at it for a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always write $\{a\in A\mid |\{b\in A\mid a\leq b\}|\leq n\}$. All those that there are at most $n$ points larger (or equal) to them. That would be the $n$ greatest values.

You can always write $A$ as $\{a_1,\ldots,a_k\}$ for some $k\in\Bbb N$, such that $a_1<\ldots<a_k$. And then $B=\{a_i\mid i>k-n\}$. There's no single way which is "commonly accepted".

Comment: thanks Asaf, the first solution shouldn't be less than n rather than less equals? for the second solution, the assumption is that {a1,…,ak} is in ascending order, how to write this assumption explicitly?

Comment: Ethan, if you require $a<b$ then yes.

Comment: actually meant this: {a∈A∣|{b∈A∣a≤b}|<n}, this will return {5,8} for n=2 from my example.   a<b shouldn't really differ from  a≤b since we can't have duplicate values in a set

Comment: Ethan, $5\nless5$ but $5\leq 5$.

Answer (score 0):

How about "Let $B=A\cap[a,\infty)$ where $a$ is chosen such that $|B|=n$, in other words: $B$ consists of the $n$ largest elements of $A$."

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can first order the elements of your set (when working with finite sets, of course).

Say you have your set $A$={$4,2,5,8,1$}.

Then you can define:

$a_1:=x  \epsilon A:x-y<0 $ for all $x \neq y$ in $A$

$a_2:=x \epsilon A, x\neq a_1 $ and  $x-y<0$ for all $x\neq y $

etc.

After you're done, you have an ordered n-tuple $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5)$ and, for

any value of $n$, just take the set {$ a_{5-n}, a_{5-n+1},..{a_5}$}